# PowerApp to Reset Passwords of other users

Tags: azure, powerapps

we have a schoolversion of Office365-Cloud. I want to write a PowerApp so that teachers can reset the password of their students.
But I'm not finding a Connector to update/reset passwords of users.
Is there a Connector for this? Is there another way to achive this?
Thank you
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you could use the [Azure Active Directory connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/). Unfortunately it doesn't have a password reset action. The exception being it allows creating a [temporary password for a new user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/#create-user). If that is sufficient for you check out this [Microsoft blog.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cbernier/2018/01/16/microsoft-flow-and-azure-ad-lets-automate/)

The functionality to reset a password does exist in the [Azure AD graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#reset-a-users-password--). You can likely use the [HTTP with Azure AD connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/webcontents/), as it should help with some of the authentication hassle ([Otherwise see this doc for the whole authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#register-your-application-with-your-ad-tenant)). Here is a [discussion with helpful tips on how to use](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/HTTP-with-Azure-AD-some-help-please/td-p/87182).